# Reading plan/text from blob url

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, url, blob

The requirement is to read the pdf text to a String using Java for testing purpose. I am not sure if it is possible to extract the content using *Blob* url extracted from the browser.

This is what I see in DOM

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="blob:https://XXX.XX.XXX.com/d4c1b2ec-bd22-4e7c-aa41-31d6ba5212b3" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/141ca21a-5f63-410b-a4c8-dc9a0554eb77" headers="Content-Length: 8159 Content-Type: application/pdf " background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56">
```

I was initially thinking there should be a way to extract the text(plain or base64 encoded) and then convert it to a specific format but I was unable to find any answer because of my limited understanding of Blob url.

This is what I have tried so far and I get null response.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.responseType = 'text';

xhr.onload = function() {
   var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;

   var reader = new FileReader;

   reader.onload = function() {
     var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;
     window.location = blobAsDataUrl;
   };

   reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);
};

xhr.open('GET', 'blob:https://XXX.XX.XXX.com/d4c1b2ec-bd22-4e7c-aa41-31d6ba5212b3');
xhr.send();
```

It is also worth mentioning that, I am executing this script using Selenium. My goal is to extract data without downloading the pdf into any local machine. So, ultimately I have two confusions:

1. Is it possible to extract data from a blob url which was created as 'Content-Type: application/pdf'?
2. Is there any other way; possibly, converting blob url to dataurl and then extract the content as String?

Comment: Blob urls are only available on the client that created it and only for the domain that created it.

Comment: @Musa I am using the same browser session. Do you mean I cannot extract text even I am on same session and same browser?

Comment: Are you running your code on a page from the same domain?

Comment: Yes same domain, same browser and also same session.

Comment: Try changing `xhr.responseType` from text to blob.

Comment: Were you able to solve it @Saifur? I have similar requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running the following script from Selenium using Javascript executor.

```
public static String generateDataUrlFromBlobUrl(String blobUrl){

    
       return String.format("var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;\r\n" + 
            "xhr.responseType = 'blob';\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "xhr.onload = function() {\r\n" + 
            "   var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "   var reader = new FileReader;\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "   reader.onload = function() {\r\n" + 
            "     var blobAsDataUrl = reader.result;\r\n" + 
            "     window.location = blobAsDataUrl;\r\n" + 
            "   };\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "   reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);\r\n" + 
            "};\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "xhr.open('GET', '%s');\r\n" + 
            "xhr.send();", blobUrl);
}
```